# AWS linux : ansible 2.9.7 using ec2.py and python 3.7 getting : ImportError: No module named boto , boto do installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ansible

i installed python 3.7

```
 python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

i have python 2.7 installed also but i dont want to use it
so i set :
set alias python=python3

ansible :

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.7
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15) [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)]
```

in /etc/ansible/hosts i set the ec2.py from here :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/stable-2.9/contrib/inventory/ec2.py
but when i run :

```
ansible localhost -m ping
```

I'm getting :

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with script plugin: Inventory script (/etc/ansible/hosts) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/etc/ansible/hosts", line 164, in <module>     import boto
ImportError: No module named boto
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with yaml plugin: Syntax Error while loading YAML.   expected '<document start>', but found '<scalar>'  The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/hosts': line 12, column 31, but may be
elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.  The offending line appears to be:  variables needed for Boto have already been set:     export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AK123'                               ^ here
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with ini plugin: /etc/ansible/hosts:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No closing quotation
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

PLAY [Ansible Ad-Hoc] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ping] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Saturday 02 May 2020  08:36:13 +0000 (0:00:00.089)       0:00:00.089 **********
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Saturday 02 May 2020  08:36:14 +0000 (0:00:00.290)       0:00:00.380 **********
===============================================================================

boto and boto3 are installed in my server 

    pip3 install boto
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Requirement already satisfied: boto in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.49.0)
```

```
pip3 install boto3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.17.0,>=1.16.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3) (0.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.17.0,>=1.16.0->boto3) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version != "3.4" in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.17.0,>=1.16.0->boto3) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.17.0,>=1.16.0->boto3) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.17.0,>=1.16.0->boto3) (1.14.0)
```

Comment: pls check this...https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3194

Comment: i did try it getting :

     |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 19.1MB/s
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (from boto3) (0.9.4)
ERROR: Will not install to the user site because it will lack sys.path precedence to botocore in /home/ec2-user/app_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages
(app_venv)[pp_venv]$ pip install --upgrade --user boto
(app_venv) [ app_venv]$ pip3 install boto
Requirement already satisfied: boto in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.49.0)

Comment: Can you try running ec2.py file like this two ways `./ec2.py --list` and `python ec2.py --list` to double confirm if any difference on environment python version?

Comment: Also try executing ansible ping with python3 interpreter `ansible localhost -m ping -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=<path>/python3'` and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from where you began (versions will be a bit different on my system but result will be the same).

You have python 2.7 installed

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

Your inventory script is executable with the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python`. This gives at the moment:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

Now, you also have python3 installed

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Since you prefer using `python3`, you create an alias so that the `python` command line points to your preferred version

```
$ alias python=python3
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9
```

You now think that any call to `python` will direct to `python3`... except this is absolutely not true when using `env`

```
$ /usr/bin/env python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

**Conclusion**: you need to change your inventory script sheebang line to one of the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: /usr/bin/env python --version
Python 3.7.6 
And in the hosts file i changed it to 
#!/usr/bin/env python3

Comment: Are you launching ansible with the same user as the one you (locally) installed boto with ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an installation issue.

```
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ansible
```

Ansible python module is /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7 which is in .local

try `which python3`
use that path for running the command
`ansible localhost -m ping -e 'ansible_python_interpreter=<path  goes here>`